# Running PostCSS compiled style sheets through purifycss with Gulp

Tags: gulp, postcss, purifycss

I have a task that first runs CSS files through postcss plugins and then through purifycss like this:

```
.pipe(postcss(processors))
.pipe(purify(['src/test/html/*.html']))
.pipe(gulp.dest(PLI.target.test.css));
```

However the CSS is not being purified.  Anyone know why?

The actual task that is running the build can be found here: [superfly-css-task-build](https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-task-build)

If you clone this [project](https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-component-button) and run `npm i && npm run test` and then look in the `target/test/css/index.css` all the un used CSS is still contained in the file even though `src/test/html/index.html` is used as the purifycss filter.

Comment: PostCSS is working, and the expected files are being written to your `dest`?

Comment: Yes just not being purified - I'm wondering whether the postcss result need to be sent through some type of transform ...

Comment: I ended up switching to uncss ... works fine now.